# Persit random UUID serving as object ID on JPA entity?

Tags: java, jpa, uuid, domain-model

I like to use a BaseDomain class for all my JPA domain entities.  In the base class, I have an object ID, stored as a String, generated from UUID.random().  The object ID is assigned at object creation.  The entity class also has a primary key, assigned by the database when persisted.

Up until this point, I've always persisted the String based object ID.  This adds an additional column to each table, but that doesn't bother me.

I was wondering - Is there any reason to persist the object id (the generated UUID)?  Or should the random UUID stay in the Java space?

I always base my domain class hashCode() and equals() methods on the UUID, not the primary key.  This is fine because the UUID stays the same for a given entity for its entire life, both in the JVM and in the database.

If I stopped persisting the UUID, what would the hashCode() and equals() methods look like?  Would it be like a two tier comparison, first using the primary key if it's not null, then using the object id, if the primary key is null?

Comment: Why don't you use the UUID as primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` is indeeed quite an issue for entities.

You do not have to persist an extra business key value if you have a 'natural' primary key, like a social security number for a person. It can be a single value or a combination of values - like a combination of name, surname, birthdate and address. If you have such a natural PK, please use it. If you do not have it, using UUID is a fine way to create one.

If you are using UUID for `equals` and `hashCode`, you should also persist it, so two instances of the same record are considered to be equal.

Your `equals` and `hashCode` should be based on this business key and not on the DB-provided id. If using the DB-provided id, all new entities are considered equal. This can lead to unexpected behaviour, especially when working with Collections.

Comment: Too late to reply, but he has UUID.random() in his Base DO. So, how will the newly created object be equal if UUID isn't used in the equal() and hashCode()

Comment: If no combination of attributes can be used reasonably as a natural PK, then there is no business level equality to speak of. Using transient (e.g. autoinc) or random PKs for business object identity can cause issues down the road, e.g. a DB crash. Not using such random or transient attributes for business equality is exactly the point.